# Passing 76k values in a filter in Cognos

Tags: sql, filter, cognos, cognos-10

I'm trying to run a report with a filter for specific email ids. Problem is that these ids list is very huge (76k email addresses).

when I run the Cognos report it keeps looping (keeps running) but never results anything for an hour and then crashes.

Can anyone provide any suggestion as how can I filter this large set of values in Cognos 10 report studio?

Comment: I don't know this flavor of SQL, but I can suggest that you add the list of emails to a formal table, and then index that table.  Then, it might run faster.  You can include your query in the question for a more focused answer.

Comment: I can't do that. There is no query, it's a report build in Cognos Report studio using a datamart.

Comment: I'd check the SQL being generated in Report Studio.  See if the filter is being passed to the database or if Cognos is attempting to filter on it's side. You don't say what RDBMS you're using, but 76k is probably more than some can handle in a in list.  You really need to look into an alternate approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Filter Expression dialog.  You can get there by dragging the field from the Source pane onto the Detail Filters box, or by using the Edit Filters option on the menu or toolbar and add an Advanced filter.  Then you can type the expression.

I've seen a problem with the Filter Condition dialog in Cognos 10.2.1 FP3 through Cognos 11.0.7.  Sometimes, with fields that have many distinct values, it gets the data from the database quickly enough, but then it spends the next few hours trying to format it into a list.  The OK or Cancel button on the dialog do not stop the process.  There is no fix.  IBM can't reproduce the problem.

Keep an eye on your CPU usage on the Cognos server.  The Audit feature in Cognos records the Windows process id.  You can use that at the command line or in Task Manager to kill the process.  After about 10 minutes, you can be pretty sure the user is no longer waiting.  I've seen this run for over 3 days with CPU usage very high the whole time.

Sorry some of this is a little vague.  I've been using 11.0.x for almost two years, so a bit rusty on 10.